# How to achieve a squashed merge commit

Tags: git, git-merge, squash

Lets say I have my master branch currently checked out

If I do a normal merge with (--no-ff) like

```
git merge release/version --no-ff
```

Then all the outstanding commits are applied to my master branch with an extra merge commit. With the merge commit you can visually see the release branch coming into master. However, lets say I only want master to contain an abridged version of the projects history and so I squash all the outstanding commits like so:

```
git merge release/version --squash
```

Then I commit the squashed commit with

```
git commit -m "Merge branch 'release/version'"
```

So now I have a nice simple squashed commit but I no longer have a merge commit and my master branch looks disjointed, as if the release branch was never actually merged. How can I have the best of both worlds and squash my commits but still have it look like a merge.

Or maybe there is a completely different approach to updating master with an abridged history.

Comment: Can’t. Squash-merging *does* mean the release branch was never actually merged. I personally recommend using descriptive merge commits and browsing those merge commits into master for a summary. A changelog might also be something to consider?

Comment: Ok makes sense. Any pointers on how to merge into master but with a simple commit. (I have a develop branch with the full history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any pointers on how to merge into master but with a simple commit. (I have a develop branch with the full history)

You could create a new branch starting from where you `release/version` branch starts, but squashing every `release/version` commit into one.

Then `merge --no-ff` that (one commit) branch.

```
git branch newBranch release/version
git rebase -i $(git merge-base HEAD newBranch)
# mark all commits except the first as "`squash`"
git merge --no-ff master
```